# How do i make a TextEditingController Required in a stateful widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I created a widget for a textfield that accepts password and I made use of stateful widget. Now I want to get the value of what is written in the text field in two different files but I can't make the texteditingcontroller required[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWkiY.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login Page should be something like this:
declare the controller in the login page then you can pass the controller to other Widget including Passwordfield, the Login page now is the owner of the controller it initialize it and dispose it.

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  late TextEditingController _passwordController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _passwordController.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        // Emailfield(),
        Passwordfield(
          controller: _passwordController,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

in the Passwordfield edit the constructor to use the controller in this Widget:

```
class Passwordfield extends StatefulWidget {

  final TextEditingController controller;

  Passwordfield({Key? key, required this.controller,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PasswordfieldState createState() => _PasswordfieldState();
}

class _PasswordfieldState extends State<Passwordfield> {

  ValueChanged<String> onChanged = (value) {};
  String hintText = "password";
  bool hidepassword = true;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: widget.controller,
      onChanged: onChanged,
      obscureText: hidepassword,
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what a friend said I should do. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can make it like this:

First you have to create controller :

```
var _controller = TextEditingController();
```

Second add this controller to your textfield

```
  TextField(
                          autofocus: true,
                          controller: _controller, // add controller here
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Test',
                            focusColor: Colors.white,   
                          ),
                        ),
```

and finally in your button check if controller is empty or not

CustomButton(
onTap: () async {
if (_controller.text.trim().isEmpty) {
showCustomSnackBar(
'Password field is empty',
context);
}
}
)

just it

Comment: I want to use the controller to get the value of the password from another file entirely

Comment: This is not what OP wants. OP wants TextEditingController as a required argument when calling the stateful widget. So, edit your answer so that it is valid to this question.